# How to set up problem involving Poisson RV

Tags: probability-distributions, problem-solving

Consider an example where customers entering a store is a Poisson random variable with $\lambda=15$. How do you find the probability that 100 or fewer people will walk into the store in any five-day period? I have set up the pmf and I know how to use it, but I have no idea where to start with this problem. If $x_i$ represents the number of people entering on each day $i$ then $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5\leq100$. Any assistance would be appreciated in setting up this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that the parameter $15$ refers to the number entering in a *day*.

Let $Y$ be the number of people entering in a $5$ day period. Then $Y$ has Poisson distribution parameter $(5)(15)$.

Now we can find an explicit formula for the probability that $Y\le 100$.

Unfortunately, it is a long sum.

For an approximation, we can, since the parameter $\lambda=75$ is large, approximate the probability that $Y\le 100$ by the probability that a *normally distributed* random variable $W$ with the same mean and variance as $Y$ is $\le 100$. We may want to use a continuity correction: we will likely get a somewhat better approximation by finding $\Pr(W\le 100.5)$.

Comment: This helped a lot. I was able to set up the problem appropriately, thanks! I did not use the approximation, I will instead be finding the result in R.

Comment: I am showing my age. In the (not so good) old days, an "exact" calculation was excessively unpleasant, so approximations were a virtual necessity. You might out of curiosity check how good an approximation you get with the normal mean $75$, variance $75$, so standard deviation $\sqrt{75}$, and whether the continuity correction gives an improvement over $\Pr(W\le 100)$.

Comment: The approximation is pretty close! If Y~Poisson(75) then $P(Y\leq100)\approx 0.9976$ while if Y is normally distributed $P(Y\leq100)\approx 0.9981$ and $P(Y\leq100.5)\approx 0.9983$. What made you think 100.5 would be better than 100? I'm not familiar with the continuity correction...

Comment: It usually gives an improvement for binomials with $p$ not too close to the two ends. However, the Poisson can be thought of a sum of many independent Bernoulli with $p$ small, so we are in the too close to the ends situation. Many thanks for checking!

Comment: The Normal approximation, as you saw, gets us very close, in the sense that the **difference** between the estimate and the truth is very small. What it is much weaker on is relative error. Here the probability we are greater than $100$ is, by the R calculation, about $0.0024$. The normal approximation gives $0.0019$, difference is small, **ratio** of the two, however, not close to $1$. There are separate brands of estimates for "tails."